# why drawing directly to the graphics object of jpanel cause significant lag to the game?

Tags: java, swing, rendering

Below are two ways to draw graphics in a java game.

First approach: 
We draw to a separate image canvas also called double buffering i think, and in the end of the frame, we draw that image to the graphics object of jpanel.

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

private Graphics2D g;

    private void init(){

        running = true;

        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    }

    private void render(){          
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        tileMap.draw(g);
        player.draw(g);
    }

    private void draw(){                
        Graphics g2 = getGraphics();                        
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g2.dispose();           
    }   
    }
}
```

Second approach:
We directly draw to the graphics object of the jpanel.

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    private void init(){            
        running = true;
    }

    private void render(){          
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        tileMap.draw((Graphics2D)getGraphics());
        player.draw((Graphics2D)getGraphics());
    }
    }
}
```

After testing both ways in a simple mario like platform game, i noticed serious flickering with the second approach. My question is why exactly is this problem seen in the second approach? Is the flickering in the second approach because of the number of draw calls to the jpanel graphics object compared to just 1 call in the first approach? I want to know what exactly is going on underneath that is causing this problem. Thank you!

Comment: You're not supposed to call `JPanel.getGraphics()` for custom painting. Can you post the code that demonstrates how these panels are used, ideally post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Double buffering is used to combat that exact reason, the flickering, tearing etc.

Without double buffering sometimes you will get to see the intermediate stage of the canvas being cleared and all the objects being redrawn. This is why you're getting flickering.

With double buffering you see no such flickering because the entire image is drawn in one single draw action.